# Symfony : Unknown database type geometry requested

Tags: symfony4

```
 php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import "App\Entity" annotation --path=src/Entity

In AbstractPlatform.php line 436:
                                                                                                               
  Unknown database type geometry requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\PostgreSQL100Platform may not support it.  
                                                                                                               

doctrine:mapping:import [--em [EM]] [--shard SHARD] [--filter FILTER] [--force] [--path PATH] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command> <name> [<mapping-type>]
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the geometry type in your doctrine.yml configuration file.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/dbal.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.